# Get Beamer's miniframes to align my subsections dots horizontaly

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

I'm currently learning how to use beamer, and I'm struggling with the miniframe command:
Some (not even all) of my subsection dots align vertically, which is really anoying though it takes way too many space that way.

I don't know if it's the default setting of this command or if I'm doing anything wrong, but I can't find anyone talking about that issue (maybe I've not been looking hard enough, if so, I apology).

here's me code, it's so simple I hardly see how this can help at all but here you go:

```
    \useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You might be looking for the outer theme `smoothbars`. It does the same as miniframes but keeps all dots in one line.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for the [`beamer` option `compress`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.8.2.3):

> Some navigation bars can be “compressed” using the following option:
>
> ```
> \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
> ```
>
> Tries to make all navigation bars as small as possible. For example,
>   all small frame representations in the navigation bars for a single
>   section are shown alongside each other. Normally, the representations
>   for different subsections are shown in different lines. Furthermore,
>   section and subsection navigations are compressed into one line.

#### Example:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}\frame{}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\frame{}\frame{}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}\frame{}
\end{document}
```

[image: headline for outer theme miniframes, using the compress option]

Comment: Okay, thanks again. I'm glad I came over here, otherwise I could have searched in vain for hours only to get depressed when realizing the solution was this simple !