# Beamer navigation bar dresden theme

Tags: beamer, navigation

I am using the dresden theme for a presentation. However, I have too many subsection in a section part of the presentation. The slides I have in a subsection are represented by circles that will highlight when I'm on the current slide. But they're too many and it makes the navigation bar too long. Is there a way to shorten it? Like having to columns of circles or only displaying the current subsection? 
I have a row of circles for each slides in each subsection. But 7 subsection makes the rows of circles too long.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme[overlystylish]{albatross}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]


\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 2}

\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 3}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 4}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 5}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 6}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\subsection{Subsection 7}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Please post a Minimum Working Example which demonstrates the problem. This will help people to help you.

Comment: Post the *code*. Otherwise people have to figure out how to produce that slide before they can even think about whether they might be able to solve the problem. Make it easy for people to help and they are more likely to find the time to do so!

Comment: Ok, sorry. I hope that this is ok.

Comment: Formatted the code for you. Indenting by 4 spaces makes it syntax highlighted in TeX.StackExchange.

Comment: Thank you. Where do I put the 4 spaces?

Comment: Please make sure your code *compiles* before posting. In this case you need to add `\documentclass{beamer}` and to remove (or supplement) `\captionsetup...` and `\setbeamercolor...` since both of those give undefined control sequence errors.

Answer (score 3):

Add the compress option:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
```

cf. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139197/get-beamers-miniframes-to-align-my-subsections-dots-horizontaly)